# ¿Por qué no cambia el color del JButton en el editor visual de Netbeans 12.5?

Tags: java-swing

Tengo un botón creado en el editor visual de apache netbeans 12.5 y cuando le cambio el background no se colorea el botón, solo se le colorea el borde, alguien sabe a que se debe este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no es el foreground el que hay que cambiar?

Comment: no no, el foreground es para el texto de dentro del botón

Answer (score 0):

Ok miren para los que sean nuevos en Apache NetBeans como yo y no saben como solucionar eso del borde solo desactiven a la casilla **borderPainted**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo le di click ahí por accidente y solucionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero le ayude a cualquiera que también buscó como cambiarlo y no lo encontró. Saludos!!!!